# nginx default_https.conf is being created constantly even when I remove it

Tags: linux, centos, nginx

I have NGINX server alongside Apache. Apache is listening on port 80 and 443, and I need NGINX to listen only in port 8020. I have set configuration files to do that, however, NGINX server does not start.

By investigating, I found there is a file called default_https.conf in directory /etc/nginx/conf.d. That file is defining 443 connection.

I removed that file, but almost immediately, it is recreated.

It seems some process is monitoring that file, and if I remove it, it will restore it.

Can you help me to solve this?

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: Are you using cpanel ?

Comment: @RedaSalih yes, I am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using **Cpanel** and **engintron** is overriding your config file.

Check out [this](https://github.com/engintron/engintron/blob/master/nginx/utilities/https_vhosts.php).